# Level 9 PI vim adventures pi puzzle

Tags: vim-adventures

How do i solve it? I have been stuck for a while there now. Hints are more preffered than answers btw.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using your newfound `count` ability along along with `G`?

Answer (score -1):

Try to type "9G" "7l" then "4k".